# access data from an Array with Swiftyjson

Tags: swift, swifty-json

No logro acceder a los valores de las llaves que se muestran en la imagen. I tried using `json[nombre_uco].stringValue` and receive nil values

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `json` is a [`JSON`](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#subscript) array of dictionaries. How about this:

```
json[0]["nombre_uco"].stringValue
```

Comment: Thank you! and I understood my mistake, your answer my problem resolved